# I can find time complexity for 'for' loop but when the condition is changed I get stuck. Is there any mathematical way to calculate time complexity?

Tags: time-complexity

Q1)

```
int a = 0, i = N; 

while (i > 0) { 
    a += i; 
    i /= 2; 
}
```

Q2)

```
int i, j, k = 0; 

for (i = n / 2; i <= n; i++) { 
    for (j = 2; j <= n; j = j * 2) { 
        k = k + n / 2; 
    } 
}
```

Comment: [Big O, how do you calculate/approximate it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3255/big-o-how-do-you-calculate-approximate-it)

Answer (score 0):

If you merely approach it mathematically, things can get very complex. most of the time it's better to walk through the logic of the algorithm.

Q1) `i` changes from `N` to `0`. every time the loop runs, `i` (which was initially `N`) halves which gives you logarithmic time complexity. `O(log N)`

Q2) The outer loop runs `n/2` times so `O(N/2)` and according to time complexity rules you drop the constant so `O(N)`.

Every time the inner loop is run, you are doubling the value of `j` which means you are closing the distance between j and n in multiplications of 2 which is logarithmic so `O(log N)`.

And since the inner loop runs for each element in the outer loop, the total time complexity is `O(N log N)`.

And notice that I am not taking `k = k + n / 2` and `a += i` into consideration because these operations run in constant time `O(1)` which is the least dominant time complexity and so has no effect in the calculations.